# Does the count of particles depend on the observer?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, reference-frames, observers, unruh-effect

The Lagrangian and Action, say in QED, is invariant to Lorentz boosts and independent of observers.

(It’s possible to convert from a Lagrangian to the Hamiltonian view via a Legendre transform $H=vp-L$ but the value would no longer be Lorentz invariant.)

Back to the Lagrangian, quantities like Energy and charge are conserved. The vector potential and Maxwell equations can be written in a Lorentz invariant way and can be decomposed in Fock space to counts $a†a$.

Still, I don't know the answer, which I think is critical to understanding fields and particles:

Does the existence of a particle, and or it's count depend on the observer?

Answer (score 2):

When considering inertial frames only (i.e. special relativity)
the number of particles does not depend on the observer.

But when considering accelerated frames (i.e. general relativity)
the number of particles does depend on the observer.

For photons this is known as the Unruh effect.
Quoted from *[Unruh effect - Explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect#Explanation)*:

> From the viewpoint of the accelerating observer, the vacuum of the
> inertial observer will look like a state containing many particles
> in thermal equilibrium - a warm gas.

Comment: Why do these particles become real in the Hawking effect (radiation)?  Is there a frame in which Hawking particles are not seen, like in the Unruh effect?

Comment: @Felicia I think the Hawking particles are not seen in the free falling frame.